# Pyspark doing http requests to HTTP API per record, but need to respect responses/minute quota. How?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say I have some data in pyspark. Also I have multiple executors.

For each record I have to do a request to an http API (I have to aggregate some more information), I'm using UDF at the moment for this.

Now the problem is that this HTTP API has a quota of 1000 requests per minute. After this limit we will get 429 (too many requests), or even kill the api, getting 504 (bad. gateway). I dont have control over this API.

I'm wondering how in this scenario (with multiple executors doing calls in parallel) I can respect the quota of calls to this HTTP.

Any good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good practice to call APIs in data processing jobs. If the Spark job fails after calling the API for all data, you should rerun the job and call the API again and again.

Try to implement another job that calls the API and saves the results in a file or database, then change the main service to simply read and use the result of the previous service.